# Show that $\frac{2}{\pi}x<\sin x<x$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, derivatives, inequality

By considering the function $$f(x)=\sin x - x$$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, show that $$\frac{2}{\pi}x<\sin x<x$$ for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

My first step was to differentiate $f(x)$, upon which I get $\cos x - 1$. However, I do not know how to procede from there.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Note 
$$ f(x)'=\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=\frac{x-\tan x}{x^2\cos x}<0,x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}) $$
and hence $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. So for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, one has
$$\frac{2}{\pi}=f(\frac{\pi}{2})< f(x)< \lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=1 $$
or
$$\frac{2}{\pi}x< \sin x< x. $$
Here $\tan x>x$ for $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ is used.

Comment: How does this help me solve the qn of $\frac{2}{\pi}<sinx<x$

Comment: @SydneySniper, yes, see the update.

Comment: why do you let $f(x) = \frac{sinx}{x}$? didn't the original qn mention $f(x) = sinx -x$

Comment: If you use $f(x)=\sin x-x$, you have to use $g(x)=\sin x-\frac{2}{\pi}x$. So it is better to use $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: I only have one doubt... how does $$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=1?$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin$ is a concave function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Thus, $\sin{x}\geq\frac{2}{\pi}x$ because graph of $\sin$ and the line $y=\frac{2}{\pi}x$

have two common points $(0,0)$ and $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},1\right)$.

Thus, for all $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ we obtain $\sin{x}>\frac{2}{\pi}x$ .

$\sin{x}<x$ for all $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ follows from the definition of $\sin$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help you.
$$\frac{2}{\pi}x<\sin(x)<x, 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$Let's use Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem: $$\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin(x)}{1-\frac{2}{\pi}x}=\frac{-\cos(c)}{-\frac{2}{\pi}}<1$$
$$1-\sin(x)<1-\frac{2}{\pi}x$$
$$\sin(x)>\frac{2}{\pi}$$